# Field of definition of isogeny of abelian varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, abelian-varieties

Let $A/\mathbb{Q}$ be an abelian variety which is not simple over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Let $\phi$ be an isogeny (defined over some number field $K$) from $A$ to its geometrically simple components. What can one say about $K$?

I think $K$ should contain $End(A_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ but not sure what else can be said.

Comment: If you take a sufficiently generic simple abelian variety $B$ over $K$ and let $A$ denote the restriction of scalars then the geometric endomorphism ring is $\mathbf{Z}^{[K:\mathbf{Q}]}$ which doesn't see much of $K$. Is there something more specific you are looking for? (Also, since $K$ doesn't contain subrings with zero divisors, did you mean to say "is contained in?")

Comment: I meant to say I think $K$ should contain the field over which all endomorphisms are defined (rather than the actual algebra which may not be a field). I guess I'm looking for something computational/algorithmic to compute a reasonable extension (eg not too big a degree) over which this isogeny can occur

Comment: I don't see why $K$ needs to contain anything; $A$ could already equal a direct sum of simple abelian varieties over $\mathbf{Q}$ and yet have endomorphisms not defined over $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: It seems you want to bound $K$. You can let $E$ denote the endomorphisms of $A$, which is a $\mathbf{Z}$-module of rank uniformly bounded in the dimension of $A$. The Galois group acts on $E$, leading to a map $G_K \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(E)$.  But $\mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbf{Z})$ has only finitely many subgroups (up to conjugation) for each $N$, which leads to a uniform upper bound on the minimal $K$. Yes, one can exploit more information about $E$ if you want better bounds.